# $ABCD $ is cyclic quadrilateral.The side $AB$ is extended to $E$ .In such a way that $BE =BC$

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

$ABCD$ is cyclic quadrilateral.The side $AB$ is extended to $E$ in such a way that $BE =BC$.If $\angle ADC =70$ degree,$\angle BAD=95$ degree then $\angle DCE$ is ... ?

Note:$ABCD$ is cyclic the sum of two opposite angles equals $\pi$.

$\angle BCD=85$ degree, $\angle ABC=110$ degree so $\angle DCE=180-x-85$ degree.

Comment: $\angle DCE=130 degree$ because BE=BC the triangle is isosceles so $\angle BCE=$\angle BEC so 45 degree

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee .can u solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ABCD is a cyclic quadrilateral and opposite angles sum up to π:
∠BAD=95 => ∠BCD=85
∠ADC=70 => ∠ABC=110

Also as in triangle BEC, ∠CBE=70 (Since, ∠ABC + ∠CBE = π (a straight line));
and as BE=BC; the opposite angles to both these sides must be equal;
i.e, ∠BCE=∠BEC;
& ∠BCE + ∠BEC = π - 70;
=> ∠BCE=∠BEC=55

Thus, ∠DCE = ∠BCD + ∠BCE = 85 + 55 = **140**

Comment: yes i done a mistake there.thank you

Comment: Trivial, but maybe add the degrees symbol in?

Comment: @SherlockHolmes - will take care of that from now on, thanks for the suggestion.